# Windows 10 Install didn't install drivers for the RAID array in the recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, recovery-partition, recovery-console

When I installed Window 10 on this computer I had to install drivers for the AMD RAID Array that Windows was being installed on.  Windows 10 created the partitions on the drive as follows:

1. Partition 0:  Recovery                  | 529 MB Hidden Partition  | NTFS
2. Partition 1:  EFI System Partition      | 100 MB Hidden Partition
3. Partition 2:  System Disk Mounted as C: | 930 GB Mounted Partition | NTFS

The "Storage Unit" is an 1 TB AMD Raid 1 Array on a Gigabit B450M Gaming Motherboard.

The issue is when I boot into the Recovery Partition, Partition 2 is not found.  This means that Windows 10 didn't install the basic AMD RAID Drivers that was loaded at install time into the Recovery Partition.  What this basically means that the 529 MB Recovery Partition is useless. No one at Microsoft has been able to help.

How do I make the Recovery Partition see the AMD RAID 1 Array?

Than you in advance,

George

Comment: How is the recovery partition loading if there are no raid drivers?

Comment: How did you verify that you couldn't load the Windows system partition after you booted into recovery? What are you trying to do? Recover a failed windows boot up? Can you add some more details to the post and possibly include what you tried with Microsoft?